# Can the Produce Flame cantrip remain continuously active in a blizzard?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cantrips, weather

Can the *produce flame* cantrip be put out by weather?

I assumed that the answer was no, and that it's constantly being generated. But I'm unsure.

Comment: It's 5e, I think its usually fair to assume I'm using 5e unless I specify OTHERWISE. Most people play 5th.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Re: your comment, we [don't guess the game](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6867/what-to-do-when-an-edit-guesses-the-system-being-used-rather-than-waiting-for-th) as a matter of policy, because A) making users clarify teaches them to use the tagging system correctly, B) guessing leads to bad answers sometimes, and C) automatically assuming every question is about D&D makes people playing other games feel marginalized and unwelcome.  As much as possible, we want to be rpg.se, not dnd5e.se.  Check out the [tour] for more intro to how we do things around here!

Comment: Very related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101528/can-you-cast-produce-flame-underwater

Comment: Also related: [How Do Combat Cantrips Function Under Water?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/118682/how-do-combat-cantrips-function-under-water)

Answer (score 11):

### The flame stays for the duration or until the spell ends

It cannot be put out by the weather or any environmental condition.

Jeremy Crawford's [tweet](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/07/07/create-bonfire-works-underwater/) about whether *create bonfire* works underwater:

> Create bonfire lasts for its duration, regardless of the environment.

So, *produce flame* lasts for its duration (10 minutes), regardless of the environment.

It might be affected by weather, flickering, shrinking in size, but the flame stays and the spell is still active. The flame is maintained by magic.