# What happens when a Shadow Blade on which Darkness has been cast disappears?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, objects

The *darkness* spells states the following:

> If the point the darkness spreads from is an object you're holding or one that isn't being worn or carried, the darkness comes from and moves with the object.

However, there is no prescription for what happens if the object that the *darkness* is following is broken ([What happens to the darkness spell if it is cast on an object that then breaks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105960/what-happens-to-the-darkness-spell-if-it-is-cast-on-an-object-that-then-breaks)) or **destroyed**, such as when *shadow blade* disappears after being let go of by the wielder/caster. What would happen to the *darkness* spell and its positioning? What would happen if **the same object** were to reappear in space, as is in this case suggested by the phrasing of the *shadow blade* spell (emphasis mine):

> While the spell lasts, you can use a bonus action to make **the sword** reappear in your hand.

To me, the most reasonable outcome in the event of the object outright **being removed from existence** is that the *darkness* stops being emitted, as the *darkness* is stated to 'come from' the object. The *darkness* would then reappear should the same object reappear, provided that the spell hasn't ended (no trigger for which has been activated).

Answer (score 9):

I see three different cases here:

1. **The object no longer exists:** There is good authority that if the target of a spell or effect ceases to be a valid target (e.g. by no longer existing) then the spell or effect ends. So, the darkness ends.
2. **The object is broken into several different objects:** Well, those objects weren't the target of the spell so the darkness ends.
3. **The object is *elsewhere*:** If the same object can be recovered from the *elsewhere* then it is still the valid target so the spell continues.

As a side note, it is not clear to me that *Shadow Blade* actually creates an object that would serve as a valid target for the *Darkness* - I could entertain arguments either way about this.

Comment: Where do you get information supporting your first point from? [This tweet from Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/931621590730653696) suggests that the spell would only be suppressed _while_ the target was invalid - which one might say is when the object doesn't exist.

Comment: The description of the _mending_ spell lists two separate halved of a broken key as **an** object, seeming to indicate that even when an object is broken, it is exactly that - _a_ broken object, rather than mechanically being a new set of objects. Additionally, the object is not the target of the spell, the point on the object is; a separate clause then dictates that the _darkness_ emanates from the object. While it can be counted as functionally the same, the differences are significant in special cases such as this.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct; the darkness would disappear when the object disappears, but when it comes back, the darkness would come back.

> the darkness emanates from the object

So if the darkness cannot emanate from the sword, there is no darkness while it has disappeared.

I would assume that the *darkness* spell would continue to exist if the object disappeared, as the darkness comes from the sword, and the sword still exists, unlike the question you referenced. There is no ending condition for the *darkness* spell, other than it overlapping with a higher-level spell that gives off light and the concentration from being broken. The object still exists, so when it comes back, it will give off darkness.

Answer (score -3):

You cannot cast darkness on a shadow blade because they both require concentration.

You can ask another player to do this, but the other player must be holding the sword to cast the darkness, as the darkness spell says "an object you are holding or one that isn't being worn or carried,".

However, another person cannot cast darkness on your shadow blade if he is not holding it, and you cannot hand it over to your friend because the shadow blade spell says "If you drop the weapon or throw it, it dissipates at the end of the turn".

Comment: Please don't delete an answer and repost it in order to negate votes.

Comment: Sorry, that was not my intention, just to hide the spelling mistakes I made.

Comment: And yet I see no spelling mistakes in either the original answer or the edit. In any case, correcting spelling mistakes are what [edit]s are for, not reposting the entire answer.

Comment: Ok, but with the actual answer, what problems you see?
I'm trying get better.

Comment: Just copying Purple Monkey's comment over: "This answer really need more of an explanation. At the moment it seems more like it's meant to be a comment. Explain that both Darkness and Shadow Blade both require concentration. Explain why Darkness saying "an object you are holding or one that isn't being worn or carried" matters." Still applicable

Comment: Understood, so you guys consider i should delete this as an answer and add as a comment, since this is not answering the main question, right?