# Would the flavoring from the Prestidigitation cantrip mask a food/drink that is otherwise inedible?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cantrips, food-and-drink

Based off of this other question about [flavoring swamp water](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/161826/38834), and highly related to this question about [the "limits" of the flavoring](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/161862/38834).

It's been kind of skirted around, but can magical "flavor" mask something that the body would normally reject if tried to consume?

A clear cut example would be poisons. Many poisons are detected by the human body as they are bitter so they are spat out. Could a poison be flavored to the point where the body would accept it? This isn't neutralizing the poison in any way, it's still poison.

**Can the flavoring of something override the natural gag reflexes?**

Comment: Are you looking for rules-based answers? If so, it might be good to provide an actual example of something that is inedible by the rules, whereas you've more-or-less assumed poisons are detectable by the human body based on their flavor alone (and not other aspects of their chemical makeup).

Comment: The question in the title of your post seems to be slightly different than the one in the body of the post. You might want to edit your question so they both reflect your intended question.

Answer (score 6):

### If something would be rejected *solely* because of its flavor, then yes, *prestidigitation* can prevent that

The [*prestidigitation*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/prestidigitation) spell states:

> [...] You chill, warm, or flavor up to 1 cubic foot of nonliving material for 1 hour [...]

We don't actually learn whether or not it also *removes other flavors* but, at the very least, *some* combination of flavor could remove the already existing ones and also add whatever you wanted. Or rather, if there was some *thing* that was mechanically being rejected by a creature *solely because of its flavor*, then yes, *prestidigitation* could prevent this because it changes the flavor from that which would be rejected.

But that's *all* the spell does, it does not change the chemical makeup of the item, or anything except its flavor. If it would be rejected by the body for any other sort of reason this spell is not going to help you.