# How exactly does sovereign glue work?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

Reading this [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/114660/40470), I came up with a question: What exactly does sovereign glue bond? The logical thing would be to assume it bonds only the surfaces it's been applied to, but reading the description:

> This [sustance] can form a permanent adhesive bond between any two Objects.  [...] the bond it creates can be broken only by the application of Universal Solvent or Oil of Etherealness, or with a wish spell.

So it would seem it creates a bond between two objects. No mention of cutting off the bonded part or anything of the sort. So...

- Is it impossible to bond creatures (I'm guessing yes)? Has it always been in previous editions?
- Is there a minimum amount of glue needed for the bond to be created?
- Would two bonded objects be treated as a single one?
- If you glued a feather to a cape and then tore the part of the cape where the feather was glued, would you be able to "mend" (with the Mending cantrip) the feather and glue back to existence?

If creatures can be bonded:

- Would you be able to heal the bonded part? If healed, would it be rebonded? Could this be used for teleportation if you glue a finger to a mountain, cut off the finger and at the other side of the world heal back the finger, thus recreating the bond?
- Since there is a bond created presumably not ended by the destruction of any of the bonded items, would you be able to "heal" a glove glued to your hand if said hand were chopped? Could this be used for infinite production of magic items with greater restoration?

And finally (open ended but secondary):

- Is there any other weird stunts you could pull using the glue?

I'm not too interested in a RAI ruling, since being glue it seems cutting off the bonded surface would let you free. Still, a definitive Sage Advice would be aprreciated (being a legendary item and whatnot).

Also, though there's a real wish for clarification, this legendary item seems to be more for laughs than anything else, so bonus point for humor to any answer provided.

Mending:

> This spell repairs a single break or tear in an object you touch, such as a broken chain link, two halves of a broken key, a torn cloak, or a leaking wineskin. As long as the break or tear is no larger than 1 foot in any dimension, you mend it, leaving no trace of the former damage.
>
> This spell can physically repair a magic item or construct, but the spell can’t restore magic to such an object.

Comment: I'm not exactly an expert on rule lawyering, but if you're going full-on read as written wouldn't you be unable to glue yourself to something? You're a creature, not an object?

Comment: That's a fair point. Will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: The "any two Objects" of the item description suggests that one could join together 2 magic items (or 1 magic item and a common item). For example a glaive wielding Warlock could glue a Rod of the Pact Keeper to the handle of the weapon, removing the need for swapping tools between attacking in melee and casting spells. This is usually a big no-no, but the rarity of the glue justifies it a bit.

Comment: I realize all these questions are more or less related, but I think they are just way too many and to diverse to be answered well in one answer. Can you please divide things up and ask each one in a separate question (or use small logical groupings)?

Comment: For what it is worth, I think these questions would still be really interesting if separated and asked separately. Though the weird stunts one is going to be too broad as an FYI.