# Are objects structures and/or vice versa?

Tags: dnd-5e, objects

An interesting issue came up in a game we were playing recently: Our party was on an airship and attacked by flying young dragons. My sorcerer cast a spell that triggered a wild magic surge and rolled a self-centered fireball (at 20,000 feet, whee!).

Here's the issue. Fireball says:

> The fire spreads around corners. **It ignites flammable objects in the area that aren't being worn or carried**.

I've noticed that certain monsters have the "Siege Monster" feature which says:

> **Siege Monster**. The [monster] deals double damage to objects and structures.

This suggests that objects and structures are legally different things and therefore Fireball would ignite an *object* but not a *structure*.

But then, perhaps a structure is a type of object? What is the nature/relationship of these two classifications of entities?

(For what it's worth, we ruled that the rope rigging was flammable because rope appears on the gear item table).

Comment: Related to, but not a duplicate of, [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/121367/are-cave-walls-considered-objects-for-the-purpose-of-spells-and-how-much-of-on)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### A structure is not an object, but is made of objects

From page 246 of the DMG and the [basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/running-the-game#Objects):

> For the purpose of these rules, an object is a discrete, inanimate item like a window, door, sword, book, table, chair, or stone, not a building or a vehicle that is composed of many other objects.

Lacking a definition from the source books, a "structure" is defined by its [common English definition](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=structure), which would be:

> the arrangement of and relations between the parts or elements of something complex.

Thus a structure might be considered to be "a building or a vehicle that is composed of many other objects".

Comment: You probably didn't even need to go with the common english. The object rules call out vehicle or building separately. But +1 anyway :)

Comment: @NautArch Agreed, but the object rules don't specifically state buildings or vehicles as structures. I wanted to solidify the assertion that 5e itself doesn't define what a structure is, and so we can fall back on the common definition to reach that conclusion with certainty.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that common sense would indicate that a burning object could certainly eventually set fire to a structure (GM adjudication, of course). I don't think this sort of thing needs to be made explicit within the rules themselves, though.

Comment: "Is made of objects" that jibes with our table-side ruling of the rope rigging being flammable but not the deck planking.

Comment: A DM could rule the structures to be combustible, meaning that when exposed to enough heat and time then it would start to burn. So a fireball would not start an airship on fire, but flammable objects on the airship left to burn could eventually ignite the ship.