# Can a incorporeal crearure move through walls?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, incorporeal

Helloy,
I´m playing a homebrew character and it states that he can take on a incorporeal form and can move through objects and creatures.

Can I also move through walls?

I know there is do general ruling about that but I just want to hear your opinion, because it seems pretty strong to me. On the other hand I can only use it once per long rest and all items drop to the ground while incorporeal.

Comment: Can you include the full text of the ability?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Make sure to take the [tour] while you're here, and check the [help] or ping someone with @ if you need additional help. Good luck and happy gaming!

Answer (score 2):

#### Homebrew problems require homebrew solutions. Ask your DM.

[This Q&A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/121367/62294) includes similarly scored, contradictory answers to the question, "Are cave walls considered objects for the purpose of spells - and how much of one?" In that scenario, it is going to be up to the DM. In this scenario, we're working with a homebrewed feature, so it is up to the DM to rule on whether or not walls are objects, and if so, if this feature lets you move through them.