# Is a dart a Tiny object for the purposes of the UA Artificer's Magical Tinkering feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, unearthed-arcana, artificer, objects

I am making a character using the [revised artificer from Unearthed Arcana](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/artificer-revisited) that came out just 4 days ago.

The 1st-level Magical Tinkering feature says you can enchant any Tiny non-magical object with various small effects. Could I apply these effects to a dart? Or would I be better off using a sling and enchanting the pebbles I throw?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour], and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: This related question may have useful information for you [What is Considered an Object?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/95532/what-is-considered-an-object) - particularly the answer that earned the *Bounty* - which is the 3rd answer with the blue label that says "+200"

Answer (score 2):

## Probably, but it depends on your DM.

More specifically, the dart certainly is an object, as specified in [What is considered an object?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/95532/what-is-considered-an-object).

Concerning the size of the object, we have some precedence for object sizes already. 
The DMG has a table on object hit points on page 247 (the table can also be found on the official DM screen). In this table, "bottle" and "lock" are listed as examples of tiny objects. Examples for small objects, the size category above "tiny", are a "chest" or a "lute".
Furthermore, in the PHB in the equipment section, Ball Bearings are specifically described as "tiny metal balls", and a Holy Symbol can be a "tiny box holding [...]".
In addition, a variety of spell components are described as "tiny".

Overall, we still don't have a clear definition of object sizes as we do for creature sizes. It's unclear if the creature size rules apply to objects as well, since creature sizes don't refer to their actual size, but to the "space a creature of a particular size controls in combat" (PHB, p. 191).

If object sizes are equivalent to creature sizes, tiny objects would be up to 2.5 x 2.5 ft. big (PHB, p. 191).
If not, you can refer to the examples listed above to determinate which kinds of objects would be considered tiny.

---

Overall, however, a dart probably counts as tiny either way, so you should be able to use it for the Artificer's *Magical Tinkering* feature. If you want to be safe, talk to your DM first, since he or she is the final arbiter on the matter.

Comment: Darts have an additional issue in that there is not, to my knowledge, a clear definition of what sort of darts they mean. The damage would seem to support the interpretation that it is the historic combat darts which were about the size of a dagger, though most people do, like you seem to, take it as something more dartboard-like dealing damage through pinpoint accuracy, which would definitely be what we see in ninja movies or what not. Obviously most people

Comment: I would downgrade that "probably" to a "maybe". A small lute and a large bottle are about the same size, so given that a dart is roughly the same size as that boundary (if not bigger), it's not realistic to say that the DM will "probably" rule that darts are tiny. It's as likely, if not more so, for the DM to say that they aren't.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes, a dart is a Tiny object

Tiny is the smallest size for objects in the game. Any object smaller than the largest example object for a Tiny object must therefore be a Tiny object, too.

The examples for tiny objects include a **bottle**. The PHB lists the weight for a bottle with 2 pounds, and a normal bottle per PHB p. 153 contains 1.5 pints of liquid. A bottle of that volume is likely [about a foot high and several inches](https://www.wine-cellar-racks.com.au/general/contentid/36/bottle-sizes) in diameter.

This is both [larger and heavier than a **dart**](https://www.dimensions.com/element/darts) that weighs 1/4 pound (PHB p. 149). (Even if we assume medieval darts for combat to be larger and heavier than sports darts).

Therefore, a dart is also a Tiny object.

Answer (score -3):

allow me to look at it in different ways:

first, it depends on what kind of dart you're thinking of. Yes, a dartboard dart would likely be tiny, but there are darts the size of a dagger... they look like big needles, and would not be a tiny object.

Secondly, I remember this kind of question coming up for another class of character I was playing before. Something like enchanting arrows. Rather than answering, my DM kindly asked me why enchant arrows and not the bow? See darts, arrows and other projectiles are basically counted as a disposable item, getting mostly 1 use out of them.  Because of that, you'll be using a lot of magic to keep enchanting darts over and over. However, if you have a sling, I am sure your DM would consider that a small item.

Remember that a sling and a slingshot are two different weapons. A sling is a small strip of leather with two leather laces attached. or the same concept created in a woven string. The way to use one is to swing it over your head, transferring centripetal force into momentum. Once you have your aim, you let go of one of the laces and the momentum forces the projectile forward at quick velocity, able to pierce the skin of even a lion. 
[image]

when folded, the sling probably takes up a space of an inch or two squared by half an inch thick? Which I do believe makes it a tiny non-magical item that would have properties to lend to all non-magical projectiles, and not just one.

Comment: Your answer by itself is interesting, but the question asked here is "Is a dart a Tiny object for the purposes of the UA Artificer's Magical Tinkering feature?". It seems to me that you interpreted the question as an XY problem (of sorts). Answering with that in mind is perfectly fine, but a good answer should also answer the actual question. In addition, you finish your answer by saying that you believe a sling would be a tiny object, due to it being size X. This is your opinion, unsupported by facts (why is an object of size X in the "tiny" category?), and therefore unsuitable for this site.