# Can Mage Hand help you fly?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, flight

I have recently seen a post on Twitter that said something along the lines of:

> "If you are a gnome and cast Reduce on yourself, you can use Mage Hand to pick you up by the collar for a quick getaway"

This sounds really cool, but I wonder if it is within the rules defined by Mage Hand.

Mage Hand [states](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mage-hand):

> You can use the hand to manipulate an object, open an unlocked door or container, stow or retrieve an item from an open container, or pour the contents out of a vial. You can move the hand up to 30 feet each time you use it.

The hand can't attack, activate magic items, or carry more than 10 pounds.

from looking around on RPG.SE I saw [that](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/95532/what-is-considered-an-object):

> An **object** is any physical thing that is not a creature:
>
> > ... targets creatures, objects, or a point of origin for an area of effect...

The same question then continues to discuss that an object is not a creature.

For completness sake, [Enlarge/Reduce](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/enlarge-reduce) shrinks the player to:

> ...and its weight is reduced to one-eighth of normal.

Which for an average [gnome weight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/gnome) of 40-45 pounds, would be below the weight capacity of Mage Hand, assuming they weren't carrying more than 10-15 pounds of gear.

So my question is: **Can I Use Mage Hand on a reduced PC, who has enough gear to be below the weight limit of Mage Hand, to pick him up and fly?**