# Is a Watery Sphere considered an object for the purpose of targeting the Otiluke's Resilient Sphere spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, objects

One of my casters cast *watery sphere* on a couple of enemies.  A second caster thought they’d combo by casting *Otiluke’s resilient sphere* on the sphere of water as an object to prevent the enemies from being able to escape.

Should this work under RAW?

Comment: Related: [What is considered an object?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/95532/33707)

Comment: Is the idea to use the water sphere to get the resilient sphere to capture all the creatures in the water at once instead of only one of them?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95025/discussion-on-question-by-blam-is-a-water-sphere-an-object-for-other-spells).

Answer (score 6):

## Probably not, but...

An "object" is a discrete (i.e. countable and not consisting of other objects), inanimate (i.e. not a creature) thing ([5e SRD](http://www.5esrd.com/gamemastering/objects/)). Counting something made of liquid as an object would at best strain that definition, and probably wouldn't qualify, hence why I'm suggesting that RAW this is a no. (Note that if you *are* OK with calling a sphere made out of water an object, this *could* work - the sphere is Large but not Huge, so in that sense it qualifies, but it'd be a bit unclear if the creatures inside would get a saving throw against the second enclosure (although probably yes)).

However, comboing it the other way round should absolutely work - i.e., targeting one of the creatures inside the Watery Sphere with Resilient Sphere, and in that case the creature would have disadvantage on its save against being enclosed due to being restrained.